# To select any range of records from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to show only a selected number of rows from the database(say from 20 to 45) I'm trying to use limit but it is not working

```
Select * 
from UsersTable 
limit 20,45
```

It is wrong since SQL Server doesn't allow this feature.

The answer that I found is

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS row 
     FROM 
         sys.databases) a 
WHERE 
    row > 20 and row <= 45
```

Can someone simplify this? I am not able to follow the above query, what is `(ORDER BY name)` in it

Say my database has the columns `Id, UserName, Email` and values in my `Id` column will be like `1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 17` -> not continuous values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL-Server 2012 and above you could use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` in following:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY name
OFFSET 20 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
```

In older versions you have to use `ROW_NUMBER()` in following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as rn 
    FROM tbl
 ) x 
 WHERE rn > 20 and rn <= 45
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY name` clause in your call to `ROW_NUMBER` is the ordering logic which will be used for assigning row numbers.  Consider the following data, and the corresponding row numbers:

```
name | row
Abby | 1
Bob  | 2
...  | ...
Jack | 20
John | 21
...  | ...
Mike | 45
```

You may visualize the subquery you aliased as `a` as the above intermediate table.  Then, you subquery `a` on the condition that row > 20 and row < 45.  In the above table, this means you would be retaining the records from `John` up to an including `Mike`.

Later versions of SQL Server also support `OFFSET` and `FETCH`, but you should learn how to use `ROW_NUMBER`, perhaps the most basic analytic function, because it will likely come up again in your future work.

Your full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    -- this subquery corresponds to the table given above
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS row 
    FROM sys.databases
) a 
-- now retain only records with row > 20 and row <= 45
WHERE 
    row > 20 AND row <= 45;
```

Comment: can u write the query so that i can have a better understanding

Comment: You are the best thanks you so much!!!!